# Android TextView.setText Crash

Tags: android, crash, textview

I'm trying to make a simple Login screen for my app, and I've implemented everything to the point where it only needs to display the information passed from the previous activity in a `TextView`. Here's the `onCreate` method from the activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

     /* Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int ID = intent.getIntExtra("USER_ID", -1);
        */


        // Create the text view
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMenu);
        txt.setText("text"); // + Integer.toString(ID));


}
```

And here's the content of the fragment xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.rma.runner.MenuActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

However, when I use this code from the developers tutorial, it seems to work, but I'd like to arrange everything graphically and then dynamically change the text from the Activity:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// Get the message from the intent
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

// Create the text view
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setTextSize(40);
textView.setText(message);

// Set the text view as the activity layout
setContentView(textView);
}
```

Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post logcat stack trace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
```

Comment: This worked, but I'm confused because I have the exact same thing on two other forms, which use activity as the setContentView parameter, and it works for those. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing something from `fragment_main.xml` you will get null because in your activity you are using `activity_menu`

So either use `txt` in `activity_menu` layout or in `onCreateView` of your fragment inflate the view

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
```

then use the view to find the textview

```
TextView txt= (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtMenu);
```

i.e.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
          TextView txt= (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtMenu);
          txt.setText("text"); return v;
    }
```